# Xcode - Why there is no "Embedded Binaries" under "General"?

Tags: ios, xcode, bundle

*I'm currently discovering Xcode / Swift / Objective-C; this question may be nonsense for experienced user, and will be removed if not relevant.*

**OS version:** MacOS Sierra 10.13.5

**Xcode Version:** 9.4.1

I created a Bundle (it contains only a .h and .mm), targeting iOS platform. I want to add a framework inside it using the *"Embedded binaries"* list, but currently only have *"Linked Frameworks and Libraries"*.

What I have done -> Created a *"Framework"* folder in my project and added the *".framework"* inside it. Then the *.framework* has been added to the *"Linked Frameworks and Libraries"*

Why does Xcode not show the "Embedded binaries" option?

Should another approach be used to add the *".framework"*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both bundles and frameworks are file structures. Bundle is meant to store files while a framework works as a library. This is the reason why you don't have an "embedded binaries" section under "General" on a bundle project.
You do not embed binairies in a bundle, you only copy them. In a framework, you can build binaries, so the "embedded binaries" option is available.

This post should be marked as duplicate, as I found the answer on SO : [Frameworks vs. Bundles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8721648/frameworks-vs-bundles)

Comment: Question is why 'Why does XCode not show the "Embedded binaries" option??'. The answer provided here does not provide insights on that. Or if there is some related information in this answer it's not obvious :)

Comment: @jeevium You can build against a framework, but not against a bundle. A bundle is just a file structure. You cannot "embed" a binary in a bundle, only copy it (when a framework embed a binary in app, it copies it into the app's bundle) so the option to "embed" is not available in a bundle.